# OpenCV imread doesn't work

Tags: c++, opencv

I have loop in my C++ code to open and process a set of images. One of those is 
[image: sample input] https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUJnp.gif

`imread` has trouble opening this specific one.`imread().data` is `NULL`.

FWIW, I'm on `CentOS` and using the latest opencv 2.4.8. Is there anyway to fix this? If not what is the easiest way to maybe open it with another C++ image library and convert it to `cv::Mat`?

Comment: what is the error you are getting while opening this specific image?. If there is any problem related to File system(example file permission/not providing the complete name of file(including the extension), no library would help us...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) documentation regarding `imread`

The function `imread` loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( `Mat::data==NULL` ). Currently, the following file formats are supported:

```
    Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
    JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Notes section)
    JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Notes section)
    Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Notes section)
    Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm (always supported)
    Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
    TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Notes section)
```

So `.gif` format is not supported by OpenCV hence `imread` is returning `NULL`.

Comment: Here are the new supported image formats for OpenCV 3.1.0: *.exr, *.hdr, *.pic, *.webp, *.pxm, and *.pnm

Comment: See miguel.martin answer here, it also provides a way to read it using VideoCapture.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252616/648298

Answer (score 3):

As I known, OpenCV does not support the gif format that, to read directly in your program, some external libraries are required. Such as http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others `cv2.imread` does not allow you to read GIFs. However, instead you can use [`cv2.VideoCapture`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) to read GIFs. For instance (in Python):

```
def read_video(video_path):
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(str(video_path))
    while video.isOpened():
        ok, frame = video.read()

        if not ok:
            break

        yield frame
    video.release()

# yes, it works with the URL (wow!)
plane_seats = list(read_video('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUJnp.gif'))[0]
animated_gif = list(read_video('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUJnp.gif'))
```

Converting this to C++ should be trivial.