# Can I run Gif with c program?

Tags: c, opencv, gif

I know that I can display a .png file, So I was thought that i can display a .gif file.
I am using opencv and i will send the code for the displaying of the .png file (that is working when you change the directory to a valid one).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>
int main(void)
{
int i;
cvNamedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window
    //create an image
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("C:\\c1.png", 1); //change to a valid directory
if (!image)//The image is empty.
{
printf("could not open image\n");
}
else
{
cvShowImage("Display window", image);
cvWaitKey(0);
system("pause");
cvReleaseImage(&image);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what happened? Error message, blank window, crash?

Comment: Have a [look here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvloadimage) in the paragraph "Currently, the following file formats are supported:" GIF is not in the list.

Comment: AFAIK there is a licence restriction on using gif format.it is not supported by OpenCV. see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23177845/5294258

Comment: Yes GIF is a proprietory format. Some years ago the owners attempted to charge a licence fee for anyone using it, but dropped the idea after widespread outrage. The patent has now expired, and GIF may be freely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there is no direct gif support in opencv.

`cv2.imread(image.gif)` is not possible.But there are many other alternatives to insert a GIF

You can use ***moviepy*** module to make it happen

[Link for moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/)

Here is an example:
**Converting a video excerpt into a GIF**

> importing *moviepy* module

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

> Then a video file is opened and selected the part between 1’22.65 (1
>   minute 22.65 seconds) and 1’23.2, reduce its size (to 30% of the
>   original) and save it as a GIF

```
clip = (VideoFileClip("frozen_trailer.mp4").subclip((1,22.65),(1,23.2)).resize(0.3))
clip.write_gif("use_your_head.gif")
```